# How to resolve this "error archiving directory: could not archive missing directory"

Tags: terraform

At the beginning of my project, there are two terraform modules: `base` and `reusable_module`.

**base/main.tf**

```
# Provide abstraction to define a lambda function
terraform {
  required_version = "0.11.7"
}

variable "env" {}
variable "role" {}
variable "function_name" {
  default = ""
}
variable "lambda_filename" {}
variable "script_env_vars" {
  type = "map"
}

data "archive_file" "package_zip" {
  type = "zip"
  # There is a bug in Terraform which does not allow '..' in source_dir, thus we use path.root:
  # https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-archive/issues/5
  source_dir = "${path.root}/scripts/"  # Path from top level module.
  # The output path has to be relative. Otherwise the buildkite will always show a diff.
  output_path = "./.terraform/${var.env}-${var.lambda_filename}.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "${var.function_name}"
  description = "Simple function"
  role = "${var.role}"

  runtime = "python3.6"
  timeout = 300  // seconds. Max hard limit is 5 min.

  filename = "${data.archive_file.package_zip.output_path}"
  // The handler is always the file name + function name "handler".
  handler = "${var.lambda_filename}.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.package_zip.output_base64sha256}"

  // Environment variables for the script.
  environment {
    variables = "${var.script_env_vars}"
  }
}
```

**reusable_module/main.tf**

```
variable "env" {}
variable "region" {}
variable "function_name" {}

provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "mylambda_role" {
  name = "${var.env}-mylambda-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

locals {
    default_function_name = "${var.env}-mylambda"
    final_function_name = "${var.function_name != "" ? var.function_name : local.default_function_name}"
}

module "mylambda" {
    source = "../base"
    lambda_filename = "mylambda"
    function_name = "${local.final_function_name}"
    env = "${var.env}"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.mylambda_role.arn}"
    script_env_vars = {
      DUMMY = "123"
    }
}
```

Module `mylambda` uses `base/main.tf` to create a lambda function.

Under `reusable_module`, there is a `scripts` directory where all the python scripts live.

Now I want to extend my project by reusing and instantiating this `reusable_module/main.tf` for different teams.

**team_template/main.tf**

```
variable "env" {}
variable "region" {}
variable "team" {}


module "team_template" {
  source = "../reusable_module"
  env = "${var.env}"
  region = "${var.region}"
  function_name = "${var.team}-essential-function"
}

# More resources specific to team_template
```

**team-sales/main.tf**

For creating a lambda per team

```
variable "env" {}
variable "region" {}

module "realdeal" {
  source = "../team_template"
  env = "${var.env}"
  region = "${var.region}"
  team = "sales"
}
# More stuff tailored for each teams
```

When I run `terraform plan -var-file=dev.tfvars` in team-sales, I got this error:

> data.archive_file.package_zip: Refreshing state...
>
> Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - module.realdeal.module.team_template.module.mylambda.data.archive_file.package_zip:
>     1 error(s) occurred:
> - module.realdeal.module.team_template.module.mylambda.data.archive_file.package_zip:
>     data.archive_file.package_zip: error archiving directory: could not
>     archive missing directory:
>     /Users/antkong/Documents/Personal/wd/StackoverflowCode/terraform/lambda/team/scripts/

The problem is the `data.archive_file.package_zip` is looking for scripts in `team_template/scripts`.

But in this case I actually have no python code in `team_template`. I simply want to continue to use the python code in `reusable_module/script`.

The separation of files must be maintained. (Conway's law etc etc)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps not applicable to your issue, but was applicable to mine when I encountered the same error.

If you mistakenly use `source_dir` instead of `source_file` for your `archive_file` you get this same error.

E.g. change this:

```
data "archive_file" "source" {
  type         = "zip"
  source_dir   = "${path.module}/lambda_function.py"
  output_path  = "${path.module}/function.zip"
}
```

To this:

```
data "archive_file" "source" {
  type         = "zip"
  source_file  = "${path.module}/lambda_function.py"
  output_path  = "${path.module}/function.zip"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can consider to merge base and reusable_module to one module and use `path.module` variable to get module path as by default terraform resolves paths relative to current working directory.

So in your case:

`source_dir = "${path.module}/scripts/"  # Path from top level module.`

Edit:

If code cannot be merged you can pass path.module as variable from reusable_module to base and then use variable instead of path.root

Comment: Is it possible without the merge? I will update the question to spell out the restraint explicitly. Mainly code ownership issue.